# FB API access still restricted after fixing broken URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

We got this restriction a few days ago: "Platform Term 7.d - App Settings Platform URLs are broken".

We have fixed the broken URL, checked it with the sharing debugger and got the right response 200, saved the changes but yet the restriction doesn't go away and we can't make our app live again. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was:

- delete the Android App Store;
- in app review, permissions and features, request advanced access for *public_profile*;
- add the Android App Store again with the package name and class name.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me without changing access. The Android section includes multiple app stores and I think one of those was failing.

Comment: What about web?